# Dvorak on iPad?

Tags: ipad, keyboard

Is there any way to enable Dvorak on iPad for apps like Pages or Notes?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Kind of a yes, no - the software keyboard can only ever be QWERTY, AZERTY, or QWERTZ. However a hardware keyboard hooked up via Bluetooth, or dock connector (or USB with the camera connector) can be set to use DVORAK:

1. Open up Settings App
2. Go to General
3. Select International Keyboards
4. Select your English Keyboard
5. Under the Choose a Hardware Keyboard Layout you can select DVORAK.

Comment: Good luck finding a hardware Dvorak keyboard that you would want to interface to an iPad. There are no acceptable products on the market. I've searched for a long time.

Comment: @WheatWilliams The above should allow you to use any hardware keyboard as a DVORAK keyboard.

Comment: I am sorry, but you are completely wrong. See my answer.

Comment: @WheatWilliams I simply meant any hardware keyboard; as in a QWERTY keyboard you found acceptable and were willing to ignore the fact that the actual lettering on the keys doesn't correspond to DVORAK. Doesn't diminish the fact that hardware DVORAK keyboards are few and far between.

Answer (score 0):

Apple finally added a Dvorak layout which can be selected in screen keyboard settings with iOS 16 in 2022.

[image: dvorak on ipad]

Comment: Before you decide a previously accepted answer is misleading, please understand that both the OP and accepted answer are 13 years old. iPadOS has obviously moved on in that time to reflect your current answer. Better to revise your answer in terms of what is now available, and better still demonstrate that your answer is a newer feature if you can provide a comparison. eg. 'Dvorak was implemented in version xyz'. You also need to state which version your answer is using.