# Dvorak on iOS 4.x?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, jailbreak, keyboard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dvorak on iPad?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1467/dvorak-on-ipad)

I want to use the Dvorak layout on my iPhone's keyboard. I've seen that there is an iKeyEx app in Cydia which offers this, but only for iOS 3.x, not iOS 4.x. **Is there a Dvorak solution on iOS 4.x?**

Note that I'm explicitly excluding external Bluetooth keyboards -- I want to have Dvorak on the on-screen keyboard.

Comment: I object to closing this as a duplicate. The stated "dupe" refers to setting up a physical keyboard using bluetooth and that's one thing I EXPLICITLY EXCLUDED in this question!

Comment: Thanks for not listening to my objection :-( at least a response would have been in order!

Comment: Better dupicate: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/230407/is-it-possible-to-have-a-dvorak-keyboard-on-the-iphone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is not. iKeyEx is the only alternative keyboard software I know of, and it has not been ported to work with iOS 4.

Comment: Drat. That was what my investigations have also turned up. Sems we'll just have to wait for some developer to do his magic!