# Is it possible to have a Dvorak keyboard on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, keyboard

I have a slight masochistic streak and would like to try learning the Dvorak keyboard layout.  I'd like to add the keyboard layout to my iPhone.  Unfortunately it does NOT appear as an option.  Is it possible to have a Dvorak keyboard layout on the iPhone?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

App Store -> type "Dvorak" -> [Dvorak for All](https://appsto.re/de/zx_t3.i) -> Have fun!

There are also a couple of paid apps.

Answer (score 4):

The built in keyboard settings only allow you to use different international layouts. You'd need to use a third party keyboard application.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I wanted to use Dvorak layout with external bluetooth keyboard on my iPad but unfortunately it didn’t work with third party apps. Happily it can be set with standard iOS settings – go to Settings, General, Keyboard, External keyboard, English and select Dvorak.

Comment: I had been using Swype, which caused this setting not to work on the hardware keyboard. Switching back to the usual Apple software keyboard made it work.

Answer (score 2):

[Gboard by Google](https://apps.apple.com/app/id1091700242) has support for the Dvorak layout.

[image: Screenshot of keyboard layout preferences with Dvorak enabled]

Answer (score 0):

iOS 16 finally added native Dvorak support to the iPhone and iPad. until now, i had depended on the 'Tempest keyboard' to provide dvorak on the phone, but it hadnt been updated for some time, and couldnt deal with new iphone screen sizes.

finally adding dvorak into iOS is a welcome fundamental addition to iOS — a feature more important than any number of useless new additions being peddled by the upgrade train. thank you apple for finally getting it right.